# shell expansions while in vim

Tags: bash, vim, vi

Being in vim.tiny in command mode and executing some shell command with `:!`, is there a way that I can benefit from the shell expansions, namely from the filename generation?
When I simply enter  key, the filename does not get expanded, instead I get the `^I` character.

Comment: What is it specifically that you'd like to do? An "expansion" can be many different things, such as variable expansion, command substitution, brace expansion, filename generation (globbing) etc.

Comment: let's say filename generation

Comment: It would be easier to answer your question if you had a specific task that you wanted to perform.  Also, your title mentions "other programs", what other programs?

Comment: let's suppose I'm editing one document and without exiting vim I want to access some other document. doesn't even have to be `:!`, it can be `:edit <somePath>/<someOtherDocu>`. but then I have to type in the whole path which I would like to avoid

Comment: @stevica Vim has tab completion for filenames. You can do `:edit some<tab>/somepther<tab>`, for example. There's also `:find someOtherDocu`

Comment: @muru Okay for me it doesn't work. I get `^I` when pressing tab. When doing it in shell it works normal. I do have to say that I'm not sure of my vim being the full blown version.

Comment: Then I suggest you start by getting Vim, or checking what you're using, at any rate.

Comment: In `nvi` you should `:set filec=\<tab>`, where `<tab>` is an actual Tab you can enter with Ctrl-V Ctrl-I or Ctrl-V Tab. You can put that in your `~/.nexrc`.

Comment: In the standard `vi` there simply isn't such feature.

Comment: Tab completion works just fine in vim.tiny (tested in multiple Ubuntu Docker containers).

Comment: May need to set wildchar